# Excel Power query : combine filelist of multiple folders as source

Tags: powerquery

I have multiple folders of which I want a filelist.  The folders are not wihin each other.

```
    = let
    Source = Table.Combine({Folder.Files("c:\folder1"),Folder.Files("c:\folder2"}),
#"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted First Characters1",{{"First Characters", "photo Type"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns3"
```

but then I get this error :
Expression.SyntaxError: Token Comma expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the initial =

After that, assuming these exist (#"Inserted First Characters1", [First Characters]) it will work

```
let Source = Table.Combine({Folder.Files("c:\folder1"),Folder.Files("c:\folder2")}),
#"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted First Characters1",{{"First Characters", "photo Type"}})
in #"Renamed Columns3"
```